# firebase functions manage multiple operations on a single database trigger

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

We are using firebase realtime DB and firebase functions.  We have wrote a DB trigger for whenever a user is updated. In this case we have a referral system. So whenever a user adds a referrer to his account then this trigger gives some reward to the referrar. Hence the user_update update trigger does the job.

This works well. Now, we need to do one more unrelated activity whenever user is updated. To be specific we want to keep total reward given so far to all the users for analytics purpose.

So, what is the best way to implement two independent operations on a single update trigger?

Technically we can embed one operation call into another but that will make like hell and messy especially if need more operations like that in future.

Comment: You have to decide - do you want "messy", or do you want reduced cost?  Is "messy" really all that bad?  Can you structure your code to make it less messy?

Comment: what is the solution with ignoring cost in this case ?

Comment: The solution is the one that you prefer.  There is no right or wrong way.  You're effectively asking for an opinion here.

Comment: well u havent read the question completely. i suggested one way of embedding calls. i dont even know how to do it as separate calls on a single object property change.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options, either use 1 realtime database trigger like now and put the logic in that function. You can make it clean and tidy by putting all the logic in separate functions that this trigger just calls

Or you can simply create another trigger exactly how you did this time and just change its export name e.g. like below. With this method all it means is you have 2 functions being called so doubling the cost.

`exports.userUpdate = functions.database.ref('/users/{uid}').onUpdate(async (change, context) => { /* LOGIC */ });`

`exports.userUpdateSecond = functions.database.ref('/users/{uid}').onUpdate(async (change, context) => { /* LOGIC */ });`

Comment: hey Jack if i go with option one which is keeping two logics into a single trigger to save on cost then how can that structure look like?   the way i think of doing that is like making first call to db query and in the response make another call. This ensures that both gets called always.  But this makes it all messy due to embedding a unrelated logic into another. is there a way to somehow keep the two calls separate in the same function and ensure both gets executed?

Comment: Really depends on how many calls you think you will be doing. Cloud functions have a very generous free tier so if you wont explode that just separate it and make it easier on yourself. Or if in the same trigger thats just a javascript question of how you separate code. Just put two functions inside the trigger, have them both return and put those separate functions in different files

Comment: any example of separating the two calls within same trigger?